# Render the same component with some state property changes on a certain route changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

How can I make changes in the some state property of a component based on the route. So, at the moment I have a component where I have defined a state property **showNotebook= true**

```
   super(props);
      this.state = {
        showNotebook: true,
        flipper: true,
        deleteModalOpen: false
      }
```

And I am using react-router, where I have a route like this

```
<Route path='/submission/:id' component={SubmissionContainer}/>
```

So now I want that if someone goes on route

```
 /submission/:id#comment.id=xyzz
```

It should show the same component as above but with property **showNotebook set to false**, so that its the same component with required changes.

I know there are similar questions asked before here, but could not find the exact solution to my problem. So apologies in advance for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check for the location pathname from the router props and if the `id` query parameter exists or not and then set the state with some logic, like this:

```
this.state = {
  showNotebook: () => {
    if (this.props.location.pathname === '/submission' && this.props.location.search)
      return false;
    return true;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Tried but its giving me:   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Comment: You'll need to use the ```react-router-dom``` library to be able to do all that.